# How to divide classes into two folders

Tags: java, package

How to divide classes into two folders (swing classes in one folder, classes that do some functionality in another).
My program is very scattered and I have a lot of classes, so I would like to organize it somehow. However when I try this wherever I have done a project of that class I get an error.
Is there any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You already marked the question with the `package` tag - that is exactly the answer.

First of all, try Oracle's official tutorial [Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html). Here the summary:

> - To create a package for a type, put a package statement as the first statement in the source file that contains the type (class, interface, enumeration, or annotation type).
> - To use a public type that's in a different package, you have three choices: (1) use the fully qualified name of the type, (2) import the type, or (3) import the entire package of which the type is a member.
> - The path names for a package's source and class files mirror the name of the package.
> - You might have to set your `CLASSPATH` so that the compiler and the JVM can find the `.class` files for your types.

<sub>(posting the error message in the question and eventually including a short example would've helped solve that specific problem)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

***I will try to explain this in a little more detail, as there are a lot of questions like this but no one has given the correct answer.***

Separation into separate folders can be considered as the current state of classes - swing classes.
They own their private members and you access them through getters.
You can also access the second package, ie variables, via the object and the getter.
In the header, specify what you want to import, ie the class that your class needs.
For example `import package.class_in_package;`
So here you are adding your package containing the class and its name.

You can also access methods as `class_name.method (parameters);`

Comment: Try to reduce the project to as few class building objects as possible, use it mainly locally, to avoid mistakes.